# Customize UserLoginInfo in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

The UserLoginInfo in Asp.Net Identity is a sealed class with only two attributes:

LoginProvider and ProviderKey

I'd like to add one additional information (such as email for example) to it so that it makes more sense to the user when managing their SSO associations.

For example, if you try to login with google, in manage account page you see

```
Provider: Google
ProviderKey: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawkmqLbSJXXXXXXXXXXXXX--c
```

Which is not very meaningful from the managing perspective. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That class is just used as a strongly typed Pair for the built in usermanager APIs that would have taken string provider, string providerKey.  If you want more info, you can either directly retrieve it in your app, or if you want to build something more reusable, you could derive from UserManager and add new APIs returning something tailored to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I understand that I can write all the code myself to achieve what I want. However, I'd prefer not have to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to. In this case there seems to be no way around since GetExternalLoginInfo extension only returns ExternalLoginInfo and it is hard coded to use UserLoginInfo.

Comment: In the next release there will be an ExternalIdentity property which hangs off of the ExternaLoginInfo which maps to what the ClaimsIdentity generated by the external login provided.  That should be sufficient for you to extract any data that was returned by the external provider.  So you could extract email via extLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity

Comment: I see, thanks for the update. Would it be possible to also make UserManager take a configurable IUserLoginInfo store? This way the external login data (email) can be stored with the UserLoginInfo, since it doesn't make sense to store this data with the IUser.

Comment: @BlueFox any info retrieved from external logins can be stored as a claim. You can extend the claims to have a provider info stored along with each claim.